# CSS color-transition not working on :hover

Tags: html, css, colors, css-transitions

Another question with using CSS.

I would like to have the header's background-color transitioning from it's current to another when hovering (due to multiple sites having different colors).

I made a [CSS-transition-animation](http://jsfiddle.net/Lodgike/ezs40t9w/) for it, but it doesn't seem to be working.
What am I doing wrong?

```
        #header
    {
    background-color: #3cff9c;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    }

    #header:hover
    {           
    /*Animation*/
    -webkit-animation: colorChange_blue 1s; /* Safari, Chrome, Opera*/
    -moz-animation: colorChange_blue 1s; /*Firefox*/
    animation: colorChange_blue 1s; /*Standard*/

    /*Safari, Chrome, Opera*/
    @-webkit-keyframes colorChange_blue 
    {
    from 
        {background-color;}
    to   
        {background-color: #008c74;}
    }

    /*Firefox*/
    @-moz-keyframes colorChange_blue
    {
    from
        {background-color: currentColor;}
    to
        {background-color: #008c74;}
    }

    /*Standard*/
    @keyframes colorChange_blue
    {
    from
        {background-color: currentColor;}
    to
        {background-color: #008c74;}
    }
}
```

Comment: did u miss closing bracket in #header:hover    ?

Comment: are you using 'currentColor' or its value #3cff9c in every from section

Comment: @matteo doesn't seem like it. From what I can tell, it's the one completely on the bottom.

Comment: `background-color;` maybe change to `background-color: currentColor;`

Comment: @singhiskng I'm using "currentColor", since I would like it to transition from the color it had before. I want to have different buttons affect different objects on multiple (multi-colored) sites, so I need it to transition from the color it's had before to the color it's going to have on hover.

Comment: @marczking Did that. Didn't solve the problem though unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about solving it without keyframes and just standard hover with transitions?

```css
#header {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #3cff9c;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}

#header:hover {           
    background-color: #008c74;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
```

Comment: Am I still able to use "currentColor" then?

Comment: well you just define the color you normally want in the `#header` and the other color on hover in the hover statement

Comment: I did now. I'm pretty new to SO. :P

Comment: sure :) Welcome onboard!